# Parallel Image Resizing

Tags: c#

I would like to ask for some help. I need to resize a flickr image using Parallel class, could you help me? That's the code I have so far.

// display selected image

```
private async void imagesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(
     object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (imagesListBox.SelectedItem != null)
     {
        string selectedURL = ((FlickrResult) imagesListBox.SelectedItem).URL;

        // use HttpClient to get selected image's bytes asynchronously
        byte[] imageBytes = await flickrClient.GetByteArrayAsync(selectedURL);

        // display downloaded image in pictureBox                  
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
        {
           pictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
        }
     }
```

I need to resize this image that I get from a search on my application using Parallel class, more specifically, resize found image(s) and save these resized images locally.

Comment: You mean [this Parallel class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel?view=netframework-4.8)? How does that apply to this problem, exactly? I'm not sure why you'd want to use that here.

Comment: Hello John Wu, the professor asked for this, I did this code that pulls the image from Flickr but I can't get it to resize using Parallel.

Comment: To be blunt... You should try to do your homework on your own and not ask for the solution here ;-)

Comment: I understand, I tried by myself for days, it's due this Sunday and I can't do it, I don't see anything wrong on asking for help. It's my last assignment on my last Semester and I can't fail the subject, sorry if it seemed as "cheating" for you. My professor did not teach ANYTHING about what she is asking, imagine having online classes during quarantine...  Thank you so much.

Comment: If you are just working with a single image, I don't think you can use Parallel to resize it, since it is going to be a compressed byte stream that can't easily be broken into parts in order to divide the work. If you have a list of images, that is a different matter. Are you working with one image or a list of them?

Comment: A list of images, when I search for a specific word like ROSE it will search on Flickr for everything related to Rose, when I click on the image name on the left side of my app, it will display the image(which is the code I uploaded).

Answer (score 0):

```
    private class ImageItem
    {
        public Image Image { get;set;}
        public int NewX {get;set;}
        public int NewY {get;set;}
        public bool OnlyResizeIfWider {get;set;}
    }

    public async Task<ParallelLoopResult> ResizeImage( string imageUrl, List<ImageItem> imageList) {
          byte[] imageBytes = await flickrClient.GetByteArrayAsync(imageUrl);
        return Parallel.ForEach( imageList, imageItem =>
        {
          // display downloaded image in pictureBox                  
          using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
          {
             var image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
             imageItem.Image = Image.Resize(image,imageItem.NewX,imageItem.NewY,imageItem.OnlyResizeIfWider);

          });
        });

    }
```

Comment: Hello, I did not understand how to implement this in my Code, also, I don't see if there is really something that resizes the picture in there, could you explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: @VictorDallarosa i missed you Resize request, i have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I am the one to advise against going for Multithreading, but in this case you absolutely should go for it. Image processing is one of the rare cases, that will be CPU bound. And with CPU bound stuff, Multithreading is unambigiously the better choice. Simple multitasking will not be enough and I could not find any information that the Paralell class can or will starts any threads. So you might have to delve deeper.

If you have to learn Multitasking or Multithreading form scratch, my advise is to use the BackgroundWorker in a WindowsForms application. It is horribly outdated for production code, but it is pretty good as "training wheels" for a part of programming that is notoriously hard to learn.

Ideally you want it done by the GPU, of course. You need a way to process a large array, with the same operation being applied to any group of or single element. That is *literally* what the GPU is designed to do. Unfortunately this is even more advanced then other Multithreading and I have very limited practical knowledge about what is current here. People with that experience would chime in under the gpu-programming and maybe gpgpu tags.